# CSS Dropdown, align down not from parent

Tags: html, css

I've got problem with alignment of CSS navbar even tho I have specified that ALL rules should revert to zero.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding:  10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
}

nav .logo {
    padding: 22px 20px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black .logo {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li a{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #151515;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:focus{
    outline: none;
    list-style: none!important;
}

nav ul li a.active {
    color: #ee0000;
}
a:hover {
    list-style: none!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
}

.dropdown {
    all: unset; 
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    margin-right:-10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: left;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Picture Lover</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/main.css" />
    <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="nav-header">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">logo</div> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Projects</a>
                <ul>                    
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Nature pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Animal pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Other pictures</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

That's everything what I got. When you hover on Projects, the dropdown menu appears on right side of the screen      " ->" instead of appearing below "↓".
I have used "all: unset" on the dropdown, to reset all the things applied to him yet it taken no positive effect ;(.

Comment: For this kind of menu, you usually want to position your submenu UL absolutely …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the element you are showing on hover is relative positioned and of course it is added according to it markup in html eg. next to Projects. It has nothing to do with setting all to unset. And I would advise against using `all` because it has no [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all).

You can find a working copy of your code below.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding:  10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
}

nav .logo {
    padding: 22px 20px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black .logo {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    position:relative;
}

nav ul li a{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #151515;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:focus{
    outline: none;
    list-style: none!important;
}

nav ul li a.active {
    color: #ee0000;
}
a:hover {
    list-style: none!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-container{
  position:absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.dropdown {
    all: unset; 
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    margin-right:-10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: left;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Picture Lover</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/main.css" />
    <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="nav-header">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">logo</div> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Projects</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-container">                    
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Nature pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Animal pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Other pictures</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer! I've removed "all:unset" and it works flawlessly. Thanks again. p.s. weird that function exists yet it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding:  10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
}

nav .logo {
    padding: 22px 20px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black .logo {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li a{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #151515;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:focus{
    outline: none;
    list-style: none!important;
}

nav ul li a.active {
    color: #ee0000;
}
a:hover {
    list-style: none!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

.dropdown-list {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover {
    text-align: right;
}

ul li:hover .dropdown-list {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Picture Lover</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/main.css" />
    <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="nav-header">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">logo</div> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Projects</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-list">                    
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Nature pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Animal pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Other pictures</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, that's what it counts. Yet I tried to mess a little bit with it and found no way of removing space between the links. Height function doesn't do much ;( How would I do it? That's how it looks now https://imgur.com/a/mPLurXd

Comment: You could try and set the `margin-top` of `.dropdown-list li` to negative values, but you will have to experiment to find a one that's working for you.

Comment: That fixed the issue, but other issue come up ;( I tried setting position:absolute or z-index to some crazy number yet it didn't work. https://imgur.com/a/uMjUHZT .. On hover other elements are moved , do you perhaps know what the issue is? If not, that's absolutely fine as you helped me a lot !

Comment: I think you would have to explicitly set `width` of `li` tags, otherwise on `:hover` your dropdown is going to take up as much space as possible, which results in moving other elements of you navbar.

Comment: Changing width from 100% to 12% fixed the issue!

Comment: That is great !

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Picture Lover</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/main.css" />
    <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="nav-header">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">logo</div> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Projects</a>
                <ul>                    
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Nature pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Animal pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Other pictures</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding:  10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
}

nav .logo {
    padding: 22px 20px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black .logo {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #151515;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav.black ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:focus{
    outline: none;
    list-style: none!important;
}

nav ul li a.active {
    color: #ee0000;
}
a:hover {
    list-style: none!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown {
    all: unset; 
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    margin-right:-10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: left;   
}
```